# Getting rid of unwanted panel plot in subplots in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib, math

I have a daily data named and share here as [data_link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xOcI9Qcn8TVvLGB-573dJGgdWepfD3Qx/view?usp=share_link). I've done all the necessary operation on it and I want to bar chart from the need eleven (11) column separately using panel plot (3x4). My code worked correctly until I plot my desired results in subplots. Since am plotting results from eleven columns in 3x4 panel plot I got '''IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 11'''. My question is how to remove the unwanted last empty panel as shown in the image below. This is the code I've been using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from math import ceil
csv_path_cont = 'path_to_my_data/data.csv'
fname = pd.read_csv(csv_path_cont)

fname['time'] = pd.to_datetime(fname['time'])
fname['month'] = fname['time'].dt.strftime('%b')

fname.set_index('time')

#=== setting 3x4 pannel plot
fname_col=fname.columns[1:-2]
month_name=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

# fixed number of columns
cols = 4
# number of rows, based on cols
rows = ceil(len(fname_col) / cols)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(45,24))
#plt.figure(j)

m=0
for i in range (3):
    for j in range (4):
        event_occurrence = fname[[fname_col[m],'month']][fname[fname_col[m]]>0]
        num_event = event_occurrence.groupby('month').count().reindex(month_name)
        num_event = num_event.fillna(0)
        ax[i,j].bar(num_event.index,num_event[fname_col[m]])
        plt.title(m)
        m+=1
        print(m)
    
fig.savefig('bar_chart',dpi=300)
```

[bar_chart_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYeVI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axis_off`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axis_off.html):

```
for i in range (3):
    for j in range (4):
        try:
            event_occurrence = fname[[fname_col[m],'month']][fname[fname_col[m]]>0]
            num_event = event_occurrence.groupby('month').count().reindex(month_name)
            num_event = num_event.fillna(0)
            ax[i,j].bar(num_event.index,num_event[fname_col[m]])
            plt.title(m)
            m+=1
            # print(m)
        except IndexError:
            ax[i,j].set_axis_off()
```

[image]